# ClassCast Exception in thread "main" when using X3D in Java

Tags: java, x3d

I'm trying to make a project that loads X3D models in Java. However, I've made two different projects shown below:

```
package simplesaidemo1;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.*;

public class SimpleSAIDemo1 extends JFrame{
    public SimpleSAIDemo1() {
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();

        // Create an SAI component
        X3DComponent x3dComp = BrowserFactory.createX3DComponent(null);

        // Add the component to the UI
        JComponent x3dPanel = (JComponent)x3dComp.getImplementation();
        contentPane.add(x3dPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

       // Get an external browser
       ExternalBrowser x3dBrowser = x3dComp.getBrowser();

        // Create an X3D scene by loading a file
        X3DScene mainScene = x3dBrowser.createX3DFromURL(new String[] { "test.x3d" });

        // Replace the current world with the new one
        x3dBrowser.replaceWorld(mainScene);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleSAIDemo1 demo = new SimpleSAIDemo1();
    }    
}
```

And

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.swing.*;

import org.web3d.x3d.sai.*;
import org.xj3d.sai.Xj3DBrowser;

public class Xj3DSpecificDemo extends JFrame {

    public Xj3DSpecificDemo() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();

        // Setup browser parameters
        HashMap requestedParameters=new HashMap();
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_ShowConsole",Boolean.FALSE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_FPSShown", Boolean.TRUE);

        // Create an SAI component
        X3DComponent x3dComp = BrowserFactory.createX3DComponent(requestedParameters);

        // Add the component to the UI
        JComponent x3dPanel = (JComponent)x3dComp.getImplementation();
        contentPane.add(x3dPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Get an external browser
        ExternalBrowser x3dBrowser = x3dComp.getBrowser();

        boolean useXj3D = true;

        if (!x3dBrowser.getName().contains("Xj3D")) {
            System.out.println("Not running on Xj3D, extended functions disabled");
            useXj3D = false;
        }
        setSize(500,500);
        setVisible(true);


        // Create an X3D scene by loading a file
        X3DScene mainScene = x3dBrowser.createX3DFromURL(new String[] { "test.x3d" });

        // Replace the current world with the new one
        x3dBrowser.replaceWorld(mainScene);

        if (!useXj3D)
            return;

        Xj3DBrowser xj3dBrowser = (Xj3DBrowser) x3dBrowser;
        xj3dBrowser.setMinimumFrameInterval(1000 / 15);

        boolean lines = true;

        while(true) {
            if (lines) {
                xj3dBrowser.setRenderingStyle(Xj3DBrowser.RENDER_LINES);
                lines = false;
            } else {
                xj3dBrowser.setRenderingStyle(Xj3DBrowser.RENDER_SHADED);
                lines = true;
            }

            try { Thread.sleep(250); } catch(Exception e) {}
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Xj3DSpecificDemo demo = new Xj3DSpecificDemo();
    }

}
```

And the error I'm getting for both when I run the code is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.j3d.aviatrix3d.output.graphics.SimpleAWTSurface cannot be cast to javax.swing.JComponent
    at simplesaidemo1.SimpleSAIDemo1.<init>(SimpleSAIDemo1.java:17)
    at simplesaidemo1.SimpleSAIDemo1.main(SimpleSAIDemo1.java:30)
```

And

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.j3d.aviatrix3d.output.graphics.SimpleAWTSurface cannot be cast to javax.swing.JComponent
    at Xj3DSpecificDemo.<init>(Xj3DSpecificDemo.java:23)
    at Xj3DSpecificDemo.main(Xj3DSpecificDemo.java:69)
```

respectively.

I've used the same `Jars` for both projects which leads me to think that it's an issue with the `Jars`. The ones that I have are

```
aviatrix3d-all_2.2.0
aviatrix3d-all-swt_2.2.0
aviatrix3d-core_2.2.0
aviatrix3d-glsl_2.2.0
aviatrix3d-utils_2.2.0
gluegen-rt
gluegen-rt-natives-linux-amd64
gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64
gluegen-rt-natives-windows-i586
jhall
joal
joal-natives-linux-amd64
joal-natives-windows-amd64
joal-natives-windows-i586
jogl-all
jogl-all-natives-linux-amd64
jogl-all-natives-windows-amd64
jogl-all-natives-windows-i586
org.j3d.aviatrix3d_2.2.0
xj3d.browser_2.1.0-nps
xj3d.cadfilter_2.1.0-nps
xj3d.replica_2.1.0-nps
xj3d.2.1-3rdparty-nps
xj3d-2.1-nps
```

I'm in dire need of help to try and fix this as soon as possible.

I'm aware that SimpleAWTSurface and JComponent are both in different classes but don't know how to fix it.

**EDIT**

When I've put `instanceOf(JComponent );` into both classes shown above, I get the following error:

```
cannot find symbol
  symbol: variable JComponent
  location: class SimpleSAIDemo1
```

Or

```
cannot find symbol
  symbol: variable JComponent
  location: class SimpleSAIDemo1Xj3DSpecificDemo
```

Comment: if you are not sure you are casting to the right type, try using `instanceOf` before casting.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35455178/displaying-an-x3d-model-in-java) seems to implythat the `x3dComp.getImplementation()` returns an instance of `java.awt.Container`, not JComponent.

Comment: Does the javadoc of X3DComponent.getImplementation say that the object returned is a JComponent? If not, why are you blindly casting it to JComponent? I've never used this library, but the property Xj3D_InterfaceType described at http://www.xj3d.org/tutorials/xj3d_application.html seems interesting.

Comment: @yogidilip I will try that, but I'm not 100% sure where 'casting' is

Comment: `JComponent x3dPanel = (JComponent)x3dComp.getImplementation();`

Comment: @yogidilip so it would be `instanceOf(JComponent x3dPanel = (JComponent)x3dComp.getImplementation());`?

Comment: @smitthy Actually you have the answer in the comments, but they are separately. If 'x3dComp.getImplementation()' is a 'Container', you cannot cast it to 'JComponent'. You should cast it to 'Container'. Secondly, you should check before casting. 'if(x3dComp.getImplementation() instanceOf Container) {Container x3dPanel = (Container)x3dComp.getImplementation();}'